# why is adx[y,z]=[[x,y],[x,z]]? (Lie algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

For lie algebra, may I ask why $\operatorname{ad}_x[y,z]=[[x,y],[x,z]]$?
Tbe following set of notes claim this is from the Jacobi identity: [https://www.math.hkust.edu.hk/~emarberg/teaching/2023/Math5143/lectures/06_Math5143_Spring2023.pdf](https://www.math.hkust.edu.hk/%7Eemarberg/teaching/2023/Math5143/lectures/06_Math5143_Spring2023.pdf)
[image]

However, the Jacobi identity means we have $$
\operatorname{ad}_x[y, z]=\left[\operatorname{ad}_x y, z\right]+\left[y, \operatorname{ad}_x z\right]
$$
but I don't think this is the same as what is given above in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claimed identity
$$
[x,[y,z]]=[[x,z],[y,z]]
$$
is false. As an example, let $L=\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$ with basis $(e, f,h)$ and $[e,f]=h$, $[h,e]=2e$ and $[h,f]]=-2f$. Assume it would hold. Then
$$
0=[h,h]=[h,[e,f]]=[[h,e],[h,f]]=[2e,-2f]=-4h.
$$
which is a contradiction.

In the proof we do not need this "equality". We only need that $[L,[I,L]\subseteq [I,L]$, which just follows from the Jacobi identity.